# Django Factory boy and django hashid field primary key: "UNIQUE constraint failed"

Tags: python, django, factory, factory-boy, hashids

I am using django hashid field in model primary keys and i'd like to use django factory boy for creating factories.

`class Camera(models.Model):
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)`

But as soon as I create factory for the second time I get this error.

`return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: camera_camera.id`

How does factory boy deal with custom fields?